# Block won't appear on specific language pages

Tags: views, 8

I have a view with a filter to show entries based on chosen language (Configure filter criterion: Content: Translation language = Interface text language selected for page). The view is placed into a block, and that block is set to show for all languages. The block's placement is restricted to the page node and all its translations, for example /node/1234, /company, /empresa, and /enterprise.

Then when I go to some of the pages, it doesn't show. It's only appearing for Global default language and ES-US, randomly. French and US English it doesn't appear for, even though the alias is exactly what I've got: /company and /enterprise.

I cannot, for the life of me see any reason this should be happening. Every setting I know of is set, and the exact same thing is working for every other block I've set up like this.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the question above. After my 'frustration post' I realized the most obvious thing. It wasn't Showing French because I didn't have French translations... I had FR-CA - French CANADIAN translations.

Doh!